# AMPL minimizing number of constraints using iterative operations

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, minimization, ampl

I'm learning AMPL to use it later in my programs. I have a small problem that I would like to solve. As the title states, I'm trying to minimize number of constraints using some iterative operation. So the problem is as following:
Assume I have 2 sets **A** and **B** and assume I have the code:

```
set A:= (1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6);
set B:= a b c;
var x{A,B} binary;    
**some_objective** ;
subject to constraint   { (i,j,k) in A, b in B   }:  x[i,b] + x[j,b] + x[k,b] <= 1;
```

now if we expand the previous constraint, the following constraints will be formed:

`x[1,a] + x[2,a] + x[3,a] <=1;`

`x[1,b] + x[2,b] + x[3,b] <=1;`

`x[1,c] + x[2,c] + x[3,c] <=1;`

`x[4,a] + x[5,a] + x[6,a] <=1;`

`x[4,b] + x[5,b] + x[6,b] <=1;`

`x[4,c] + x[5,c] + x[6,c] <=1;`

this means, for **y** subsets in **A** and **z** elements in **B**, we will get a total of **y*z** constraints (in our case it is 2 x 3 = 6 constraints).

Now if we change the constraint to:

```
subject to constraint   { (i,j,k) in A   }:  prod {   b in B   }    (x[i,b] + x[j,b] + x[k,b])    <= 1;
```

which will result in:

`{(x[1,a] + x[2,a] + x[3,a]) * (x[1,b] + x[2,b] + x[3,b]) * (x[1,c] + x[2,c] + x[3,c])} <= 1;`

`{(x[4,a] + x[5,a] + x[6,a]) * (x[4,b] + x[5,b] + x[6,b]) * (x[4,c] + x[5,c] + x[6,c])} <= 1;`

it should have the same result as the previous form yet we decreased number of constraint from **y*z** to **y** which is a good improvement!!
Another improvement is to logically **and** the constraints:

```
subject to constraint   { (i,j,k) in A   }:  forall {   b in B   }   (   (x[i,b] + x[j,b] + x[k,b])    <= 1  );
```

which will result in:

`{(x[1,a] + x[2,a] + x[3,a])  <= 1}  &&  {(x[1,b] + x[2,b] + x[3,b])  <= 1}    &&  {(x[1,c] + x[2,c] + x[3,c])   <= 1};`

`{(x[4,a] + x[5,a] + x[6,a])  <= 1}  &&  {(x[4,b] + x[5,b] + x[6,b])  <= 1}    &&  {(x[4,c] + x[5,c] + x[6,c])   <= 1};`

The problem is, when we do this, we are changing the problem from linear or quadratic to a non-quadratic equation and **cplex** can't solve it anymore :/

Is there any work around or any trick to enable me to do this without converting the problem to a non-quadratic problem (at least to be solved using **cplex**)?

It is useful also to say that `x[1,a] + x[1,b] + x[1,c] = 1` and this is true for any other element in **A**. Your help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that the constraints using product are not equivalent to the original constraints. For example, a solution `x[1,a] = 1, x[2,a] = 1, x[3,a] = 1` with the rest of `x` equal to zero satisfies the constraint formulated with `prod` because `(x[1,a] + x[2,a] + x[3,a]) * (x[1,b] + x[2,b] + x[3,b]) * (x[1,c] + x[2,c] + x[3,c]) = 3 * 0 * 0 = 0 <= 1`, but doesn't satisfy the original constraint `x[1,a] + x[2,a] + x[3,a] = 3 <= 1`.

You can use logical `&&` or `forall` with [IBM/ILOG CPLEX CP Optimizer](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-cp-optimizer/) (ilogcp) which is available for all AMPL/CPLEX users, but I doubt this will be any better to having separate constraints. You can find more about `ilogcp` on the [“Logic” and Constraint Programming Extensions](http://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/) page which also include the information on how to obtain it (if you have a CPLEX license you should be able to get ilogcp too). This solver will accept constraints of the form:

```
subject to c{(i,j,k) in A}: forall {b in B} (x[i,b] + x[j,b] + x[k,b] <= 1);
```

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, I didn't think of this case. Thanks. But you said that I can use the logical `&&`, can you give me an example? cplex shows me the error message `CPLEX 12.6.0.0: logical constraint _slogcon[1] is not an indicator constraint.` when I use the `subject to constraint   { (i,j,k) in A   }:  forall {   b in B   }   (   (x[i,b] + x[j,b] + x[k,b])    <= 1  );`. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information about ilogcp.

Comment: Thanks @vitaut and sorry for the late reply